# Could pass value using delegate in TVCell the same way as in TVController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates

Like I have a TVCell, and I define a method like this:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    _categoryName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _categoryArray[row]];
    [self.delegate categoryPickerCell:self didSelectCategory:_categoryName];
}
```

Why here `[self.delegate description]` is `null`? Because in my another TVController, I use the same way to pass delegate like below:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control{    
    MapPoint *mapPoint = view.annotation;   
    NSString *cinemaName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",mapPoint.name];
    [self.delegate mapViewController:self didSelectCinema:cinemaName];
}
```

Is it due to the view controller in this one ? And only can Controller use this method, Cell cannot?

Comment: No you can use the delegate pattern anywhere.  You'll need to make sure delegate of TVCell is being set (and not being set to nil at some point).

Comment: Yeah, it has been set. Actually it works well in the TVController using the same method (put the uipicker into an independent view controller). But now I change it to a Cell, not Controller anymore (when click the table cell, uipicker popup automatically). Why now this method doesn't work?